# how to search with sql for similar values on different fields

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 fields which occasionally they have the same value , but not on the same record .

so for example :

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |  |
| 2 |  | 7 |
| 3 | 100 |  |
| 4 |  | 100 |

how do i get the id's for each matching ?
for value 7 i should  get in return id 1 and 2 etc ..

Thanks ,
Zohar

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 7 in (value1, value2);
```

If you only want to return rows where *both* columns have the value, then this works for the data you have provided:

```
select t.*
from t
where 7 in (value1, value2) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id <> t.id and
                    7 in (value1, value2)
             );
```

EDIT:

If you want to find the pairs, use `join`:

```
select t1.id, t2.id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.value1 = t2.value2 and t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks .
The problem with this approach is that i need to specify the values myself .
i want the query to find the pairs . so the result will return the values and corresponding id .
this table have millions of rows .

Comment: @zoharos . . . That is simpler.  Just use `join`.

Comment: @zoharos . . . Then you have million of examples where this occurs.